# java.sql.SQLException: Table 'myTable.owner' doesn't exist

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using JPA to create and access a database. My database consists of two tables? These two tables have a `@OneToMany` relationship. However, when I run my application, I am getting a  `java.sql.SQLException`.

I have done some research but none of the solutions online seem to work for me. The first solution suggests to replace `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` with `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

The second solution consists of Including `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false` into application.properties.

None of these solutions worked.

Car.java

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

        ....

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner")

    private Owner owner;

        ....

}
```

Owner.java

```
@Entity
public class Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long ownerid;

        ....

    @OneToMany(cascade =CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="owner")
    private List<Car> cars;

        ....
}
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.root=INFO
server.port=8080
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/cardb
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.generate-dll=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto=create-drop
```

Here is the `Exception` I am getting :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Table 'cardb.owner' doesn't exist
```

**EDIT:** I am using MariaDB and the database's name is cardb. So, when I run the application, it should create `cardb.car`, `cardb.owner` and `cardb.car_owner`

By the way, the database is properly created when using `H2`. Does it mean the problem comes from MariaDB ?

Comment: Can you try `update` instead of `create-drop`?

Comment: Please provide more information. The decisive question is: which table is supposed to be named `myTable`?

Answer (score 0):

@JoinColumn(name = "owner")
should be 
@JoinColumn(name = "ownerid")

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `@Table` in your entity classes.

Define Car as,

```
@Entity
@Table (name="car")
public class Car {
...
}
```

and

Owner as below,

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "owner")
public class Owner {
...
}
```

Comment: Same problem: `java.sql.SQLException: Table 'cardb.owner' doesn't exist`

Comment: Can you try changing "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" to "update" in your applicaiton.properties.